# mysqli num_rows does not return correct number of rows - all values checked

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysql-num-rows

I'm trying to show `icon.envelop.2.gif` if there are any messages with `message_status = 2`. However for some obscure reason this query returns 0.
What have I missed here?

The `$_SESSION['user_id']` is valid, and so is `$access_level`. I have checked my table and I have 1 input with the correct `message_receive` number and I have also tried using `message_to_stab = 5` which is the correct number.

**This is the information in my database:**

- `message_id = 1`
- `message_receive = 697`
- `message_status = 2`
- `message_to_stab = 5 or message_to_stab = NULL`

**This is my information in session and access_level:**

- `access_level = 5`
- `$_SESSION['user_id'] = 697`

**This is my code:**

```
$sql = "SELECT message_id FROM private_messages WHERE message_status = 2 AND (message_receive = ? OR message_to_stab = ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die ("Database error: <br>" . $sql . "<br><b>Error message:</b> " . $mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $_SESSION['user_id'], $access_level);
$stmt->execute() or die("Something went wrong");

if($stmt->num_rows != 0){
    $html .= 'icon.envelope.2.gif';
}
else{
    $html .= 'icon.envelope.gif';
}

$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

Here is the problem, no errors, I want BOTH mailing symbols to be like the one under `status`.

[image: Image showing messaging error]

Comment: `@Gjert I. Gjersund` please try my answer once. and tell if any problem is still there. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use `$stmt->fetch()` to solve the problem. I had to change the query to LIMIT 1 in order to prevent errors when more than 1 unread message available.

```
if($stmt->fetch()){
    $html .= 'icon.envelope.2.gif';
}
else{
    $html .= 'icon.envelope.gif';
}
```

PS: Better answers are more than welcome. I still dont know why `rowCount()` or `num_rows` didn't work.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I haven't been able to test it yet, but does rowCount() not work because there is only 1 column selected?

Comment: No that is not the case. i never got this. `rowCount()` must work either record is 1 or something else.